# Check if button graphic is equals an image

Tags: image, javafx

So i'm making a little application with a button and a Image in there.

```
btnPlay.setGraphic(new ImageView(imagePlay));
```

Now I've an ActionEvent on it to switch the Image, if the button get clicked (Like the pause Button in Spotify). The problem is, I've no clue and found nothing in the internet how i can handle this with a if - else Statement. And that what I tried is not working.

```
        btnPlay.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

            Image imagePause = new Image(path);


            if (btnPlay.getGraphic().equals(imagePause)) {
                btnPlay.setGraphic(new ImageView(imagePlay));
            }

        }
    });
```

Thanks for every answer.

Comment: the basic issue is not the image, it's the missing modeling of the state: f.i. have a booleanProperty playing that can be toggled on/off, register a change listener with that property and in that listener update the graphic of the button (or the image of the ImageView) - an aside: there is no reason the re-create the image/view on each state change, load it once and re-use

Comment: Reusing the `Image` also allows you to compare the `Image` using `==` to check for reference equality. If you want to avoid this for some reason, there's still the [`Image.getUrl` method](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#getUrl()). My suggestion would be using a `ToggleButton` and binding the `image` property of the `ImageView` based on the `selected` property of the `ToggleButton`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the code below demonstrates using a `BooleanProperty` in your application that holds the current "is playing media" state:

```
BooleanProperty isPlaying = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
```

By adding a listener to that property, you can ensure the correct icon is always displayed on the Play button:

```
isPlaying.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (newValue) {
        playButton.setGraphic(pauseIcon);
    } else {
        playButton.setGraphic(playIcon);
    }
});
```

Then just have your `Button` also toggle the state of that `BooleanProperty`:

```
playButton.setOnAction(event -> {
    // Toggle the isPlaying property
    isPlaying.set(!isPlaying.get());
});
```

---

Here is a complete sample application you can run to test it out yourself:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PlayButtonToggleSample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple Interface
        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        // Create our two ImageViews to hold the icons we need
        ImageView playIcon = new ImageView("play.png");
        ImageView pauseIcon = new ImageView("pause.png");

        // BooleanProperty to track whether or not the application is currently playing media
        BooleanProperty isPlaying = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

        // Create a simple button with an image
        Button playButton = new Button();
        playButton.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        playButton.setGraphic(playIcon);

        // Add action for the button
        playButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            // Toggle the isPlaying property
            isPlaying.set(!isPlaying.get());
        });

        // Now, add a listener to the isPlaying property that will toggle the icon used on the playButton
        isPlaying.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue) {
                playButton.setGraphic(pauseIcon);
            } else {
                playButton.setGraphic(playIcon);
            }
        });

        root.getChildren().add(playButton);

        // Show the stage
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Sample");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I **don't** found a way how I can check if the Image is equals, but I found a way how I can solve this problem. This is my solution:

```
    ImageView imgPlay = new ImageView(new Image(path + "play.png"));
    grid.add(imgPlay, 1, 0);

    ImageView imgPause = new ImageView(new Image(path + "pause.png"));

    imgPause.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            grid.getChildren().remove(imgPause);
            grid.add(imgPlay, 1, 0);
        }
    });

    imgPlay.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            grid.getChildren().remove(imgPlay);
            grid.add(imgPause, 1, 0);
        }
    });
```

Comment: see my comment to the question - I'm sure you want to revise your solution :)

Comment: Definitely not a good solution, poisn. Check out kleopatra's comments.

Comment: @Zephyr yeah I saw the solution, but I don't really understand that (or have the knowledge maybe). I'm trying :-)